# How to change "et al." to norwegian

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to change "et al." in my citations to "m.fl." all over in my document. I am using `natbib` and the bibstyle `agsm`. I have also defined `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`, but it seems to not do the work either.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

some of my code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,norsk,twoside,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

..
    \section{Referanser}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    \renewcommand*{\refname}{Referanser}
    \bibliography{referanser}
```

Comment: It would be good to have a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to help here.  Bibliography-tweaking questions in particular are heavily dependent on the exact packages you use, and their parameters.

Comment: Don't translate "et al.": it is an abbreviation of et ‎(“and”) and alii ‎(“others”) from Latin.

Comment: @campa - I wouldn't say the new posting is a duplicate, at least not a particularly faithful one.

Comment: @PaulGaborit it may not be the author's decision to make.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you provide `norsk` as an option when running `\documentclass`, you needn't specify the option again while loading the `babel` package.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a modified version of the file `agsm.bst`. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `agsmno.bst`. (The string "no" is supposed to be short for "norwegian"...) Do not edit a file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `agsmno.bst` in a text editor.
- Replace all six [6!] instances of `" et~al."` with `" m.fl."`. (Observe that there's a space after the opening double quote in both strings.)
- Save the file  `agsmno.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file (the one with the `\bibliography` instruction) or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsmno}`, and re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the changes made to the bibliography style file.

Off-topic: It appears that you're using the `natbib` citation management package. I therefore recommend you load the `har2nat` package as well. Loading this additional package will ensure full interoperability of the `agsm` and `agsmno` bibliography styles with both `natbib` and -- should you choose to use it -- `hyperref`. (The `agsm` bib style is distributed with the `harvard` citation management package; the `har2nat` package "translates" some macros from `harvard`-speak to equivalent `natbib`- speak.)